# How can I capture Memberpress user info after signup

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, memberpress

I'm currently working on a website where users can purchase subscriptions using memberpress, I want to capture the user data after the signup process is completed and the payment transaction is also completed as well.

If I add the member through dashboard manually I'm able to catch the user info as there is no payment gateway is involved, with this code

```
function mepr_capture_new_member_added($event) {
    $user = $event->get_data();
    //mail('myemail', 'mp user added', 'new user added successfully');
  }
  add_action('mepr-event-member-added', 'mepr_capture_new_member_added');
```

As I'm new to WordPress development I don't know how I can access this data on my other page templates, that's why I'm sending an email to test if it works or not I was able to figure out the action hook for the transaction-completed event, but it doesn't seem to work properly. Here is the code

```
function mepr_capture_new_one_time_sub($event) {
    $transaction = $event->get_data();
    $user = $transaction->user();
    //mail('myemail', 'user purchased subscription', 'user-transaction-completed event captured '); }

add_action('mepr-event-non-recurring-transaction-completed', 'mepr_capture_new_one_time_sub');
```

I've read the complete memberpress documentation but the resources related to development are not what I'm looking for, they gave an option for webhooks and I can capture the data on zapier after user signup and payment transaction is completed but I need the data on my website so Zapier is not an option, they also provide the rest API but I want to capture the user information on 'signup and transaction complete' event and I don't think so that's possible with rest API, Please let me know how I can overcome this issue, any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

After searching for about 2 days I was able to figure out a way to capture the user after signup process is completed and the user's payment goes through the payment gateway, the way I'm doing it right now is when a signup process is completed user is redirected to thank-you page and a querystring containing subscr_id is passed on that page and I'm capturing that subscr_id and fetching the user from the database manually and its working perfectly fine, the process is seamless, and I can use the data on my other page templates as well.

You can simply get subscr_id from $_GET['subscr_id'] and use that to capture the user associated with this subscription from the table 'wp_mepr_subscriptions' and then use the user id to fetch the user detail from 'wp_usermeta' table of the wordpress, hope it helps someone else :)